# How to pass USERID & password as an argument in ansible playbook

Tags: linux, ansible

```
adjoin -u <admin_account> dev.abc.plc.uk --zone Dev -s VC123.dev.abc.uk -c "OU=Computers,OU=Centrify,DC=dev,DC=abc,DC=uk"
```

I want to execute above command to join the server to active directory using ansible script with admin account which should prompt for the password.

This is for a new Linux server, running RedHat 6.1, ansible 2.6.2.

```
 - name: 6.Join the server to Active Directory
      shell:adjoin -u <admin_account> dev.abc.uk --zone Dev -s VC123.dev.abc.uk -c "OU=Computers,OU=Centrify,DC=dev,DC=abc,DC=uk"
```

Comment: How would you do it outside ansible in bash ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion...I am running this inside Ansible yml file itself.
In bash, I simply run like below & this will prompt for the password.

adjoin -u <admin_account> dev.abc.uk --zone Dev -s VC123.dev.abc.uk -c "OU=Computers,OU=Centrify,DC=dev,DC=abc,DC=uk"

Answer (score 1):

You can use vars_prompt ansible module and capture the password.